# MySQL/PHP mass update multiple records with one query using CROSS JOIN on same table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a PHP script that runs ever 60 seconds.  It queries an external database to check if any records have been updated.

It's basically a booking system that requires manual approval or rejection of booking requests.

The system is being modified to allow customers to request changes to already accepted bookings.

I'm looking for the quickest way to update the local database in one transaction (so customers can access a web portal to view the status of each booking etc).

I thought I found it but I'm experiencing unpredictable results (not all of the records are being updated all of the time) but I'm not sure if it's because of the query I'm using or other factors.

This is my method of updating the records:

```
UPDATE bookings
CROSS JOIN (SELECT * FROM bookings WHERE parent_id IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) AND processed = 0) AS Child
SET
bookings.date = Child.date,
bookings.time = Child.time,
bookings.name = Child.name,
bookings.email = Child.email,
bookings.telephone = Child.telephone
WHERE bookings.id = Child.parent_id
```

I'm calling the edited booking record the 'child' and the main booking that has had the requested change on it the 'parent'.  If the change request is accepted then most of the parent record (fields I choose) should be updated with the data from the child record.  A child record is considered a child if it has a value in the parent_id field.

The above example would be created dynamical in PHP but for simplicity, 1, 2 , 3, 4 and 5 would be the IDs of the master/parent bookings that have had accepted change requests, thus requiring an update.  The inner query is getting the necessary child records.

I guess my real question is: should my query work, does it look correct and logical?  Should it work even if a field in the original booking was empty and now has a value and visa versa if it's requested that a field now have a blank or null value?  Maybe I'm using the wrong method entirely!

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: How many child have one parent? One or more than one?

Comment: @krasipenkov At any one time (when the script is executed etc) a parent will only have one child and a child will only have one parent.